# CSS to JSON Parser or Converter

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, parsing

I'm working on a non-web platform with no HTML or CSS layer, just a pure JavaScript implementation.

I would like to load a CSS file as a text string using AJAX, parse the CSS into a JS objects or JSON, and then use utility library to interpret what styles should be applied to an element in the DOM tree.

How would I do that?

Comment: How will you represent your CSS stylesheet in JSON?

Comment: That's part of the question. I'm open to suggestion. It doesn't have to be strict JSON... just a JS representation of the styles would be good.

Comment: See also here: http://lesscss.org/ ... Might help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're looking for a "JavaScript CSS parser".

Have you looked at either of these?

http://www.glazman.org/JSCSSP/

or

http://bililite.com/blog/2009/01/16/jquery-css-parser/

The first one looks like a good fit, but if you like jQuery then maybe you'd prefer the second one.

HTH

Comment: I looked into JSCSSP. the documentation is limited. I can't find out how to access the parsed CSS in JS. I inspected the CSS and they do a good job separating the styles but there's not a good way to access the properties   {"parsedCssText": "h1 { margin-top: var(m...pright: var(myMargin);}"}

Comment: jquery css parser might be a little tricky. jquery won't work as our platform doesn't' have HTML and CSS.

Comment: @JONYC: `var parser = new CSSParser();  
 var sheet = parser.parse('body { color:black; }', false, true); sheet.cssRules[0].declarations[0].property; // statement returns 'color'` See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARxBX/2/).

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I guess Josh3736 deserves the points for this!

Comment: I couldn't find a way to parse back from a JSON object to CSS using JSCSSP. JSCSSP parses the CSS to JSON great, and the structure it uses is just what we need, but we also need a way to parse back the JSON object to CSS. Any ideas / suggestions ?

Answer (score 12):

I looked at both the links @amir75 suggested. The first looked best, but the code was far too long for what I was doing. I decided to put a lightweight script together. It doesn't use jQuery, but you can if you want to load a CSS file using `.get()` etc. Take a look at the example.html and the js console output to get a look at the structure. You can choose to keep the order of the elements if you're using comments in the CSS, or otherwise it will still keep the order of the elements but not those of the comments while using a simpler JSON structure.

https://github.com/aramkocharyan/CSSJSON

Usage:

```
// To JSON, ignoring order of comments etc
var json = CSSJSON.toJSON(cssString);

// To JSON, keeping order of comments etc
var json = CSSJSON.toJSON(cssString, true);

// To CSS
var css = CSSJSON.toCSS(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code "without" any external library:

```
function cssToJson(cssStr){
var tmp="";
//handling the colon in psuedo-classes
var openBraces=0;
for(var i=0;i<cssStr.length;i++){
    var c=cssStr[i];
    if(c=="{"){openBraces++;}
    else if(c=="}"){openBraces--;}
    if(openBraces==0 && c==":"){
        tmp+="_--_";
    } else {
        tmp+=c;
    }
}
cssStr=tmp;
cssStr=cssStr.split("\"").join("'");
cssStr=cssStr.split(" ").join("_SPACE_");
cssStr=cssStr.split("\r").join("");
cssStr=cssStr.split("\n").join("");
cssStr=cssStr.split("\t").join("");
cssStr=cssStr.split("}").join("\"}####\"");
cssStr=cssStr.split(";\"").join("\"");
cssStr=cssStr.split(":").join("\":\"");
cssStr=cssStr.split("{").join("\":{\"");
cssStr=cssStr.split(";").join("\",\"");
cssStr=cssStr.split("####").join(",");
cssStr=cssStr.split("_--_").join(":");
cssStr=cssStr.split("_SPACE_").join(" ");
if(cssStr.endsWith(",")){
    cssStr=cssStr.substr(0,cssStr.length-1);
}
if(cssStr.endsWith(",\"")){
    cssStr=cssStr.substr(0,cssStr.length-2);
}
cssStr="{\""+cssStr+"}";
try{
    var jsn=JSON.parse(cssStr);
    return jsn;
} catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    return null;
}
}
```