# Convert HTML Element's "Style" Attribute to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to convert the style attribute of an HTML element to a JSON object with JavaScript / jQuery. How should I go about this?

**Clarification:**
Lets say I have `<div style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center;"></div>`, so I want a JSON object: `{font-size: 14px, text-align: center}`

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to do. Take the style declarations and put them in an array, using jQuery?

Comment: Lets say I have `<div style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center;"></div>`, so I want a JSON object: `{font-size: 14px, text-align: center}`

Comment: @Anonymous - You should edit and add that to the question.

Comment: Question is clear. Have you tried running a for loop and concatenating property names and their associated values to a var?

Comment: @Anonymous, you might check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240778/css-to-json-parser-or-converter

Comment: Just so you're clear, [there is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) plugin,

#### HTML

```
<element id="myElt" style="foo: 1; bar: x; baz: none;"/>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var styles = $('#myElt').attr('style').split(';'),
    i= styles.length,
    json = {style: {}},
    style, k, v;


while (i--)
{
    style = styles[i].split(':');
    k = $.trim(style[0]);
    v = $.trim(style[1]);
    if (k.length > 0 && v.length > 0)
    {
        json.style[k] = v;
    }
}

alert($.toJSON(json));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/aT77q/

Comment: Sorry but this fails with values like: url("http: // www.google.com"); for example...

Comment: i think you should edit the v=$.trim(style[1]) to v=$.trim(style.splice(1,style.length).join(":"))

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
function getStyles(el) {
    var output = {};

    if (!el || !el.style || !el.style.cssText) {
        return output;
    }

    var camelize = function camelize(str) {
        return str.replace (/(?:^|[-])(\w)/g, function (a, c) {
            c = a.substr(0, 1) === '-' ? c.toUpperCase () : c;
            return c ? c : '';
        });
    }

    var style = el.style.cssText.split(';');

    for (var i = 0; i < style.length; ++i) {
        var rule = style[i].trim();

        if (rule) {
            var ruleParts = rule.split(':');
            var key = camelize(ruleParts[0].trim());
            output[key] = ruleParts[1].trim();
        }
    }

    return output;
}

var element = document.querySelector('div');
var css = getStyles(element);
console.log('css ->', css);
```

**output:**

```
{
    color: "green",
    border: "1px solid orange",
    marginLeft: "15px",
    padding: "20px",
    backgroundColor: "white"
}
```

**fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/grt6gkpe/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can also roll your own -- it's not that hard. The [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Style) for `style` gives ample data:

```
function getStyles(element) {
    var style = element.style;
    var ret = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < style.length; ++i) {
        var item = style.item(i);
        ret[item] = style[item];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You code is returning `font-size` and `text-align`, which of course are undefined in the DOM style object.

Comment: @MattMcDonald: The accepted answer does so as well. Generally speaking, I don't think you can do better because as the documentation states, `style` allows you to read only the *calculated* styles of the element.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps ever so slightly an off answer, but I ran into this thread looking for a way to turn the style attribute into an object, ready to pass to $(el).css(). I wound up writing this little plugin to do it:

```
$.fn.styleAttributeToObject = function () {
    var style = $(this).attr('style'),
        asObject = {};
    if ('string' === typeof style) {
        $.each(style.split(';'), function (i, e) {
            var pair = e.split(':');
            if (2 === pair.length) {
                asObject[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            }
        });
    }
    return asObject;
};
```

Hope it's helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a string from element.style.cssText and split it up

```
function styleObject(element){
    var obj= {},
    str= element.style.cssText.match(/([^:]+\: *[^;]+); */g),
    tem, i= 0, ax, L= str.length;
    while(i<L){
        tem= str[i++].split(/: */);
        obj[tem[0]]= tem[1];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

//example-
styleObject(elementreference);

```
/*  value: (Object)
{
    display: 'block;',
    margin-left: '1ex;',
    margin-right: 'auto;',
    position: 'relative;',
    width: '1193px;',
    z-index: '100;',
    visibility: 'visible;'
}
```

But why not just use the cssText string as the value?